# C++ CImg create image from array

Tags: c++, image, multidimensional-array, cimg

I have got three 2d-arrays (one for each colour RGB) in C++ with values stored inside which represent the colour value. I would like to reconstruct an image out of that and I wondered what the best method for this would be since none of my attempts worked so far.

Problem 1: There is hardly anything out there about that, at least my google searches gave zero results for that topic :(

Problem 2: The operator(), .data() and .fill() functions from CImg don't work for some reason for me. I have an open post about this here:

[CImg funtions problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60685142/c-cimg-access-violation-reading-location)

However, rather than just focusing on this very particular error that I describe in the other post, I wanted to ask here what a proper coder would do with this task. Would you maybe solve the task completely differently? The lack of attention for my other problem on google at least gives me the feeling that this question is halfway justified and hence, I wanted to open this thread about it instead of making the other question off-topic.

I read the code of conduct beforehand and as far as I understood it this is the way to handle such scenarios and to avoid being off-topic - however, if I have misunderstood something, please bear with me and let me know - I am relatively new here.

Thank you for your consideration.

Comment: The easiest-to-program solution is to iterate through every pixel in the image and apply the colors to them. https://cimg.eu/reference/group__cimg__loops.html this page should help

Comment: Thank you! I got it to work (see other post - one of the arguments were wrong, the counting does not start from 0) and with this all operators that I tried (and that are listed on the website you gave) seem to work. Cheers!

Comment: No problem :) glad it helped

Comment: @steak_Overcooked If you would like to create a proper answer you can. Of course link only would not be a proper answer, but if you wanted to add more context around it and explain the solution, so that it can help others, please feel free to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there's a more sensible way, but you could use something like this (untested):

```
CImg<> R,G,B, combined;
combined.draw_image(0,0,0,0,R);
combined.draw_image(0,0,0,1,G);
combined.draw_image(0,0,0,2,B);
```

Comment: I am not sure how to make your example work - however, a loop over the operator() or .data() thing (see other post) worked as long as I don't set z=0 at the image creation and with this logic most of the CImg functions suddenly seemed to work. Thank you for your consideration though!